# unable to split csv file into multiple csv file in beam python

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm trying to split the csv file into multiple csv file based on the column value . 
But now i'm using the below code but i'm able to create file based on the filter value but files have empty records. can you please any one sort me out the issue.

Sample Input data : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6tlk.png)
Sample output files: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBT8q.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJlAu.png)

Please find the steps i have followed

1. Reading csv file as dict in python3.
2. Extarct key from dict and convert values of key into list.
3. Iterate through list and filter the dictionary based on list values
4. Write into separate files

`

```
import apache_beam as beam
import csv
import uuid
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
dict_reader = csv.DictReader(open(input_file,'r'))
insert_date_lst = []
for i in dict_reader:
    insert_date_lst.append(i.get("key"))

class TagData(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        key = element.get('key')
        yield TaggedOutput(key, element)

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:

  data = p | "dict_read" >> beam.Create(dict_reader)
  for i in list(dict.fromkeys(insert_date_lst)):
      filter_data = data | "filter"+i >> beam.Filter(lambda x : x['key']==i)
   processed_tagged_log = filter_data | "tagged-data-by-key " >> beam.ParDo(TagData()).with_outputs(
       *list(dict.fromkeys(insert_date_lst)))
   for i in list(dict.fromkeys(insert_date_lst)):
      processed_tagged_log[i] | "save file %s" % uuid.uuid4() >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_file + i ,num_shards=0,shard_name_template="",file_name_suffix='.csv')
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please add sample input and output to your question. Also please fix the code indentation.

Comment: @Sach I have added sample source file and expected output files. can you please look into it

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to do? you are reading full file to insert keys in a list and using that list to create side output, so why not do it in python, what is the need to use apache beam?

Comment: I would like to do in cloud dataflow so i'm using beam with python SDK . I know we can do this in simple way in python. But for our requirement i need to do this in beam